# DIV with added contenteditable="true" does not focus on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I'm using jQuery to add the content editable attribute to a DIV.

```
$('div').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
```

When I click it, I don't get the focus effect I get when I click on already contenteditable DIVs. It only focus when I click it another time.

This happens in every single one of my browsers – Safari 5, Chrome 18, Firefox 8. Is there anyway I can make it behave as it should?

Comment: setup a fiddle on jsfiddle.net showing your problem

Comment: What do you mean by 'focus effect'? Neither of these appear to have it: http://jsfiddle.net/aSPKQ/

Comment: I realize I had some other click events interfering. It does work. My bad. The question is kind of invalid. What should I do with it?

Comment: I am facing same issue , Unable to make editable div focus on single click  -- Let me know if you have solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realized I'm having this problem because the element is also a jquery-ui draggable and the click event has been hijacked.

Comment: too late for you, but for others who are facing the same problem: wrap your editable content in a div, give the parent div the ability to drag, then bind a click event to the child element (the one with editablecontent="true". like this (assumed the id of your editable element is editableElementId): document.getElementById("editableElementId").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.target.focus();
    })

Comment: this one works too: <div onclick="(function(e){e.focus()})(this)" contenteditable="true">

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/VV7BW/1/ seems to work. `$('div')` might be your problem, that will get all divs I think, but only apply the attr to the first one (but don't quote me on this)

Try giving your div an id, then access it with `$('#id')`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same bug trying to add the `contenteditable` attribute on a mouse event. Using the `mousedown` event, it doesn't work. Using the `click` event it works fine...

The `id` attribute doesn't change anything in my case.